# UIlabel use much memory with big amount of text

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have UITable view, in uitable cell I use own label with very, very long text. In result this uilabel spent approximately 100 mb. (In this case - memory warning and then crash). How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UILabel *message;
    CGSize textSize;
    CGSize fullSize = CGSizeMake(300, 100000);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    message = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    message.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 20);
    message.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    message.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    message.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    message.tag = 103;
    message.numberOfLines = 100000;
    message.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:message];
    [message release];
}
    else
{
    message = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
}
NSData *messageData = [[grandData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
NSString *tempContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
message.text = tempContent;   // text about 10000 symbols in length
[tempContent release];
   textSize = [message.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:fullSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
message.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, textSize.width, textSize.height + 6);

return cell;

}
```

I use message label (not cell.textLabel) because have some labels which display other information (I cut excess  code).  Height of cell change dynamically depending on amount of text in

```
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: What is the size of the text you are using? Have you tried having the text on different labels do the cells can be reused?

Comment: reuse cell not labels, while cell visible in view - labels allocates in memory

Comment: Depending on the size of the text, it's possible that not all of the text is visible. If you separate the text into different labels, each label into different cells, you will avoid having all of those labels on memory. What is the size of the text you are putting into memory?

Comment: size of text set in code snippet. This is not simply having dynamically changed text, back gradient of cell and more other labels which allocate in one cell divide it on few cells

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking memory.

When you create:

```
NSString *tempContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

you are not releasing `tempContent` afterwards.

You should change your code to something like this:

```
NSData *messageData = [[grandData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                       objectForKey:@"content"];
NSString *tempContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData   
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
message.text = tempContent;   // text about 10000 symbols in length
[tempContent release];
```

Comment: not this don't work. I use release, when I copied code accidentally cut this code. Now fix it.  When this cell disappear from screen memory back

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with Swift 3 
in despite of the fact that i use dequeueReusableCell

```
class StepTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
 }


    var fontSize = CGFloat(14)
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StepCellWithoutImage", for: indexPath) as!  StepTableViewCell


                    customCell.stepNumberLabel.text = "\(cellInfo.index + 1)"
                    customCell.contentLabel.font =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
                    customCell.contentLabel.text = step.content
                    debugPrint(step.content?.count)

                    return  customCell

}
```

the problem is really when it try to increase the font and reload the tableView